# Webmin - Error - File not found

Tags: arch-linux, webmin

I have Webmin 1.590 on Arch Linux and I'm getting "Error - File not found" message when trying to access certain functions such as "Upgrade Webmin" and "Install Module" because it seems that I'm missing the .cgi script files for them.

I tried installing these files straight from downloadable package from Webmin's website but only got another errror "Missing Content-Type Header".

So what can I do about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

How did you install Webmin? Your installation is broken. You should probably try uninstalling it and reinstalling.

The "Missing Content-Type Header" error probably means the Perl path is incorrect in the files you replaced...look at the shebang line at the start of the file. It should point to wherever perl is installed on your system.

i.e. if perl is in /usr/bin/perl, the shebang should be:

#!/usr/bin/perl